# What is the hexadecimal code to adjust transparency?

Tags: html, css

What is the hexadecimal code to adjust the transparency of a color? For example, #FF0000 is opaque red, what makes it, lets say 20% transparent.

Comment: Use following hexadecimal code for transparent text colour: #00FFFF00